# Pixelating webcam data during livestream

Tags: webcam

I'd like to pixelate the video data that's being sent on Skype or Zoom when using my laptop's webcam. Is there a tool or a program I can write that can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Gotta good laugh outta this one.  Just put your trousers on sir during business meetings?!

Sorry could not help it. Try PineTools.

Comment: Hahaha, thanks, I'll check it out. It's so that people don't see me use my phone during really boring meetings.